# I want to optimize this SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have query like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `kpbaru`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getAllUmurPegawai`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllUmurPegawai`(IN id_user VARCHAR(20),i_tahun INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currdate INT;
    DECLARE birthdate INT;
    DECLARE numRows INT;
    DECLARE numIteration INT;
    DECLARE tempMonth INT;
    DECLARE umur INT;
    SET numRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pegawai);
    SET numIteration = 1;

    WHILE numIteration <= numRows DO
        SET currdate = i_tahun; 
        SET birthdate = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT TGL_LAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING = numIteration AND ID_USER=id_user)));
        SET umur = currdate - birthdate;
        SET tempMonth = (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT TGL_LAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING = numIteration AND ID_USER=id_user)));
        IF umur < 56 THEN
            UPDATE pegawai SET pegawai.STATUS_PEGAWAI='Belum Pensiun',pegawai.BULAN_PENSIUN=tempMonth,STATUS_PENSIUN=1 WHERE pegawai.INDEXING = numIteration AND ID_USER=id_user;
        ELSE 
            IF umur = 56 THEN
                UPDATE pegawai SET pegawai.STATUS_PEGAWAI='Pensiun',pegawai.BULAN_PENSIUN=tempMonth,STATUS_PENSIUN=1 WHERE pegawai.INDEXING = numIteration AND ID_USER=id_user;
            ELSE 
                UPDATE pegawai SET pegawai.STATUS_PEGAWAI='Pensiun',pegawai.BULAN_PENSIUN=tempMonth,STATUS_PENSIUN=0 WHERE pegawai.INDEXING = numIteration AND ID_USER=id_user; 
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET numIteration = numIteration + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

i want to optimize this query, because this query will search each age in eeach people. This query runs very slow if we have big data (>1000 rows). Any one know how to optimize it?

I've tried some query like this:

```
UPDATE pegawai AS p LEFT JOIN(SELECT INDEXING, CAST(CASE WHEN (i_tahun - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(SELECT TGL_lAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE ID_USER=id_user))) < 56 THEN 'Belum Pensiun' ELSE 'Pensiun' END AS VARCHAR(20))AS statusPegawai, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(SELECT TGL_LAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE ID_USER=id_user))AS bulanPensiun, CAST(CASE WHEN (i_tahun - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(SELECT TGL_lAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE ID_USER=id_user))) <= 56 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT)AS statusPensiun FROM pegawai WHERE ID_USER=id_user GROUP BY INDEXING)AS m
    ON p.ID_USER = m.ID_USER
    SET p.STATUS_PEGAWAI = m.statusPegawai, p.BULAN_PENSIUN = m.bulanPensiun, p.STATUS_PENSIUN = m.statusPensiun
    WHERE p.ID_USER = id_user;
```

but it still wrong. Here the error is:

Query :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllUmurPegawai`(in id_user varchar(20),i_tahun int) BEGIN  DECLARE currdate INT;...
```

> Error Code : 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(20))as statusPegawai, extract(month from(select TGL_LAHIR from pegawai w' at line 29

Solution will be apreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast to `varchar` use `char` instead.

From the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

```
The CONVERT() and CAST() functions take an expression of any type and produce a result value of a specified type. 

The type for the result can be one of the following values: 

- BINARY[(N)]

- CHAR[(N)]

- DATE

- DATETIME

- DECIMAL[(M[,D])]

- SIGNED [INTEGER]

- TIME

- UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

Comment: i've converted it into char(n), but i still have this error message:

Query : CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllUmurPegawai`(in id_user varchar(20),i_tahun int) BEGIN  DECLARE currdate INT;...

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int)AS statusPensiun from pegawai where ID_USER=id_user group by INDEXING)as m
 ' at line 28


Or you've any solution to optimize my query?

Comment: As you can see in my answer `int`is also not permitted. use `signed`or `unsigned` instead.

Comment: one of your subqueries returned more than one line. –  Jens 9 mins ago

which subqueries Jens?

Comment: I can not say it without knoledge about your database.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your query correctly I think you can do this in a single update statement for a user:-

```
UPDATE pegawai
SET STATUS_PEGAWAI = IF(i_tahun - YEAR(TGL_LAHIR) < 56, 'Belum Pensiun', 'Pensiun'),
BULAN_PENSIUN = MONTH(TGL_LAHIR),
STATUS_PENSIUN = IF(i_tahun - YEAR(TGL_LAHIR) <= 56, 1, 0)
WHERE ID_USER=id_user
```

Comment: can i optimize the looping part Kickstart? I have to update every age of the employee and i have 4000 employee in my database.. How to make that update faster? :D
Thanks for your answer.. :)

Comment: The code above should remove the need for the loop. If you want to do it for all users then just remove the WHERE clause. Afraid I can't test it as you haven't posted your table declares or any sample data.